# Função para obter valor em texto de uma URL acessada

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tentei criar uma pequena função, ficou dessa forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var value0;
            $.get( "file.php?id=1", function(data){
                value0 = data;
            });
            arrayAmount[0]=value0;

            var value1;
            $.get( "file.php?id=2", function(data){
                value1 = data;
            });
            arrayAmount[1]=value1;

            var value2;
            $.get( "file.php?id=3", function(data){
                value2 = data;
            });
            arrayAmount[2]=value2;
        }

        function buyVps(){
            var vpsDetails='Processor : '+arrayProcessor[sliderValue]+' GHZ'+'\nRAM : '+arrayRam[sliderValue]+' MB'+'\nRAID Storage : '+arrayStorage[sliderValue]+' GB'+'\nMySql Databases : '+arrayMySqlDB[sliderValue]+' GB'+'\nMonthly Price : '+'R$ '+arrayAmount[sliderValue];window.open(arrayLink[arrayBlocks[sliderValue]], '_blank');
        };
```

Eu preciso que ele pegue o valor que é retornado quando a URL é acessada. Não é em JSON, retorna em texto simples, somente um valor como por ex: 79.90

Preciso que seja dessa forma, utilizando o `arrayAmount[0]=`, pois faz parte de outra função.

Como devo ajustar o script?

Comment: Se é para retornar um texto simples como vc disse, pq então está passando parâmetros na url, id e periodicidade?

Comment: Esses parâmetros são para retornar o valor do plano correto, cada plano possuí uma ID diferente. O retorno é apenas texto.

Comment: Se vc der um `console.log(data);` te retorna o que?

Comment: @sam... Pois é, eu notei que ele sempre retorna undefined, e não o valor.

Comment: Hmm, não sei realmente como deve ser feito... se puder me indicar algum tutorial onde eu possa me informar melhor eu agradeço.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com o restante da função.

Comment: Essa url que você busca seu texto simples é uma API?

Comment: O lance é usar a variável dentro do Ajax: https://jsfiddle.net/Lsf8d5u4/2/

Comment: @sam... O problema é que são vários arrayAmount: `arrayAmount[0],arrayAmount[1],arrayAmount[2]` e cada um com parâmetros diferentes na URL, então naõ teria como eu colocar diretamente na função que imprime o valor no HTML.

Comment: @PedroPaulo... sim

Comment: Mas aí vc joga como parâmetro da função o que for diferente. Bom a princípio é isso, o Ajax vai buscar em outra página as informações, e isso pode demorar desde frações de segundos a até alguns segundos, então tem que construir o código que se encaixe nisso.

Comment: @sam... Fiz um teste usando sua dica, continuou dando undefined.

Comment: O `data` só tem valor dentro do callback do Ajax. Fora é _undefined_.

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma ideia de como eu faria:

```js
var arrayAmount = Array();

$(document).ready(function(){
    // quando o documento estiver ok, buscar os dados no servidor
    buscarNoServidor();
}

function buscarNoServidor(){
    $.get( "http://localhost/2018/buscar_valor.php?id=48&periodicidade=monthly", function(data){
        arrayAmount[0] = data;

        // ao receber os dados, chamar as demais funções
        buyVps();
    });
}

// só chamar esta função, quando tiver resposta do servidor
function buyVps(){
    var vpsDetails='Processor : '+arrayProcessor[sliderValue]+' GHZ'+'\nRAM : '+arrayRam[sliderValue]+' MB'+'\nRAID Storage : '+arrayStorage[sliderValue]+' GB'+'\nMySql Databases : '+arrayMySqlDB[sliderValue]+' GB'+'\nMonthly Price : '+'R$ '+arrayAmount[sliderValue];window.open(arrayLink[arrayBlocks[sliderValue]], '_blank');
};
```

Obviamente você vai adaptar para a sua necessidade, mas a ideia é que você  só pode usar o valor depois que tiver a resposta do servidor.